# Read excel file using Java

Tags: java, excel, odbc

I am trying to read excel using Java API.  It is throwing error.

Code is as follows -

```
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=D:\\SelFrame\\Business_Script\\Controller.xls");   
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

Error is as follows -

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Environment use -

```
JDK 1.7 (64 bit)
O/S = Win 7 (64 bit)
MS office = 32 bit
```

Comment: Did you setup the ODBC data source?

Comment: Yes, I setup ODBC data source of name DBQ. But no luck

Comment: There are many API (open, free and commercial) to ready xls from java. Why not use them. Eg Apache POI

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string to the following.

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DBQ");
```

Comment: It throws error : The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents. It's save my day time ago.

http://poi.apache.org/

Check this post:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/